# How to declare a variable without initting it to nil in Lua?

Tags: variables, lua, scope, local, declaration

I've found it very useful to do something like:

```
if not variable then
    variable = value
end
```

Of course, I'd usually rather that variable was local, but I can't declare it local in my if, or it won't be accessible.

So sometimes I do:

```
local variable
if not variable then
    variable = value
end
```

The problem is that when I iterate over this code, the variable declaration sets the variable equal to nil. If I can live with a global value (I can), I can get around it by just not declaring the variable outside of the if block.

But isn't there some way that I can both have my local value and let it keep its value?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. If you create a new local variable, then *by definition* it's value will be nil. So what variable exactly are you trying to check the value of? Do you want to declare a new variable or not?

Comment: Is it a recursive function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the way `or` is defined in Lua gives you a nice idiom to avoid the `if` altogether:

```
variable = variable or value
```

If variable is `nil`, `or` will evaluate to its second operand. Of course, this will only work, if `false` is not a valid value for `variable` (because `false` and `nil` are both "false" as far as `or` is concerned).

However, you still have the problem that you need to declare the variable somewhere. I suppose your problem is that in the case of a global loop you think you have to do either:

```
while condition do
    variable = variable or value
    process(variable)
end
```

(which would make `variable` global) or

```
while condition do
    local variable
    variable = variable or value
    process(variable)
end
```

which is pointless because `local` limits the scope to one iteration and reinitializes `variable` as `nil.

What you **can** do though is create another block that limits the scope of `local` variables but does nothing else:

```
do
    local variable
    while condition do
        variable = variable or value
        process(variable)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank for you answers.  Actually, I was wondering because I wanted to test if "local limits the scope to one iteration" was true or not.

Comment: Perl and Ruby both have a similar idiom using the '||' or operator, and so you see code such as, val||='default';  this value or default idiom is very useful.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Yup, you can do the same in JavaScript. Probably in most languages that have a concept of "truthy" and "falsy".

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to test the scope of locals inside loops:

```
local a = "this is external a"
for x = 1, 3 do
    print(a)
    local a = "THIS IS INTERNAL a"
    print(a)
end
```

If you run this you'll get:

```
this is external a
THIS IS INTERNAL a
this is external a
THIS IS INTERNAL a
this is external a
THIS IS INTERNAL a
```

If  the local **a** inside the loop survived to the next iteration then after the first print it should have printed only "THIS IS INTERNAL a" as the internal **a** would shadow the external **a**. The two strings alternating means that the internal local **a** never survives the bottom of the loop.

Of course, even if it did survive you would have the problem of the internal local declaration shadowing the previous iteration's local **a** each time through the loop. Essentially you would be unable to access the previous iteration's version of **a** and by the third iteration you would have 3 separate internal locals, only the last of which would be accessible. It would be the same as if you had done this:

```
local a = "THIS IS INTERNAL a"
local a = "THIS IS INTERNAL a"
local a = "THIS IS INTERNAL a"
```